# Add column to a table using EF on the fly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webforms

I am trying to creat a system which user can creat/remove tables and add/remove columns from it. Is this possible to do with EF ? I have searched a lot durinig last 2 days and i have read lots of example but they didn't helped me !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes i am using code first

Comment: As i said before by users I dont mean end users ! So please dont concern about security issues!

Comment: You might want to update your original post if you don't want to hear that anymore.  You can't expect everyone to scan through every comment under other answers.

Comment: And I apologize about recommending ODP.NET in an earlier comment.  I don't know why I got the impression that you were using Oracle.  I must have dreamed it.  But you will want to look at ADO.NET for what you are asking.  EF is definitely not what you want in this case.  Good luck.

Comment: Also, please try to not use exclamation points at the end of every sentence! Use periods like everyone else! Every time I read your comments I think you're yelling at me and I'm just trying to help!

Comment: Sry. Just a chatting habbit. I didnt ment yelling.

Comment: The reality is that you didn't provide much information and showed no research to us at all. Despite saying that you "searched a lot in the last two days", the only thing you mentioned was EF, which doesn't at all do what you're looking for. To which I query: what exactly were you searching for? I included a lot of content, below, to answer your question and point you in the right direction. At the end of the day, this is _your_ Bachelors degree and you should be the one coming up with a _solid_ project idea/project plan. I gave you more than I should have to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your guid i wish i could rate up your post at least . But i cant do that because of not having at least 15 rep. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be letting your users write code, and your code should not be writing and compiling more code or starting other apps. As such, no, this is not what you are looking for.

If you *really* wanted to (and I advise against this), what you could do is create a system where users create and add/remove columns from tables using C#. That part is fine. However, since EntityFramework is an ORM that gives you strongly-typed objects to represent your tables/records/etc. there would be no use for it in a system such as this, as you will not have any way to get those strongly-typed objects without the app restarting.

I think you may need to reconsider your approach.

**Side-Note:** If by your "users" you are actually referring to the developers on your team, then if you are all using EntityFramework Code-First and configure your application for auto-updating (which Add/Drops tables) then yes, this is built in. All you would have to do is update the strongly-typed class with the new columns or by removing columns to be deleted and the next time that you build and run the database should be automatically updated. Issues usually arise, however, if you have any data in your tables.

**On Creating an MIS**

If you really want to proceed and build your own MIS with a UI then you are looking at things from the wrong angle. Here is some beginning process to get you started out:

1. **Requirements:** I'm assuming you have all the requirements and stuff, otherwise you're starting development too soon and that's just too far out of scope for StackOverflow
2. **Architecture:** Start off by drafting your architecture. An MIS is a system for managing databases with tables and fields. You want your users to be able to create and manage database tables code-free. Well, you can do this by having your architecture simulate tables (a table of table names and IDs, and another with column names, IDs, parent table IDs, and values, etc.; this is a good system for a CMS but not an MIS because big data would crush it) or by actually administering a Database (a lot of security considerations and things to work around here)
3. **Terminology:** Get your lingo down pat. Are you talking about a database table or one of your custom tables, etc.
4. **Frameworks:** Depending on your architecture, EF may be an option. If you are making a CMS then EF could easily be used in the architecture that I gave an example of, above. For an MIS, it is probably not the right choice.
5. **Development Planning:** Plan out the rest of your development and break it into smaller problems. Based on your comments, you pretty much just asked how to architect and develop your Bachelors final project for you. You need to do this yourself. Besides, if this was a question that I could give you a succinct answer that does what you want and is appropriate for StackOverflow then companies that provide MISs wouldn't be making as much money as they are.

Comment: What can i do ?! I am trying to creat an MIS and in want to be able to add/delete tables and feilds with out changing the code ! I dont want to allow any user to alter database ! I just want to make it easy for myself to make similar systems quickly in the future ! So please guid me if there is any way to do this!

Comment: Yes i mean developers ! But ! I want to do this with out changing code ( at least manualy) . I want these magics to be happened at run time automatcily ! I want to make a system that would make it easy for us to make other systems with out codeing ( at lewst for the db part ) . I know what you are saying ! But thats not what i want !

Comment: You can write that from scratch, but EntityFramework is not going to help you. The second paragraph is more what you are looking for. I don't usually say this, but in this case I will: if you are not sure how to start, then I would honestly advise you not to. An MIS is complex system and is typically used to house valuable data. It should be developed and architected by experts who can take responsibility for supporting it. If you don't know where to start then this is a fun project, but not something you should put in production. Find an existing system out there that you can use.

Comment: What you are looking for is a way to take the coding out of coding. You can use a tool like SQL Management Studio to create your tables and relationships, or you could use Visio to build out your DB structure and have it automatically create/update your tables. Either way, you will need code to connect to those DBs and look at the changed tables. Ergo, you are still going to have to write code. I have written a few CMSs in my time which house even more strictly-defined data than an MIS, and the arcitecture had to support that. You can do that too, but that's not what you're describing.

Comment: To be hounest thats my bachlor final project ! So i have to do this !

Comment: I just want to be able to add/delete table/columns at run time ! I wonder why should such thnig be that much compilcated !

Comment: Because of securities. My advise to you is to pick a different final project. If you really can't then ask your professor if you can create a CMS instead. It can be entirely web-based, will be very DB heavy, will do exactly what you are looking to do (only you would call them "Data Items" or "Items" or "Components" or something like that instead of "Tables"; and "Fields" or something instead of "Columns"), and will be much easier to implement without all of the security concerns. You could also use EF to make your life easier.

Comment: Lets forget about MIS and security stuff. To make it simple is there any way to alter table on the fly ?  I didnt get the part you said let call them data items or ... .

Comment: That's if you're creating a Content Management System, e.g. Wordpress, Sitecore, Umbraco, Drupal, DotNetNuke, etc. You could give the models that user's define to hold the data for their page whatever name you want. Those were just examples. In all honesty, I have voted to close this post as it is highly off-topic for SO. I gave you some ideas for your final project and that was more than I should do here, as SO is not the right forum for that. Whatever you choose, do it yourself and make it yours. :) Good luck!